# "There are currently no power options available" message when using BitLocker on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, bitlocker, shutdown

I have a Windows 10 IoT Enterprise version 21H2 (not in a domain).

I encrypted C partition using BitLocker configured to auto-unlock using the TPM module of the PC.

Each time I enable BitLocker, the "Shutdown" / "Restart" options disappear from the power options in Start menu.
(Showing "There are currently no power options available.")
Every time I disable BitLocker, it fixes the issue.

Looked for solutions on the web and tried the following, but nothing helped:

1. Run powercfg -restoredefaultschemes
2. Run DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
3. Run sfc /scannow
4. Change the current power option name / restoring the power scheme
5. Run power troubleshooter
6. Log on with different account

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve it?